# How to search for selected checkbox in an divsion using elementRef in angular

Tags: angular, angular7, e-commerce, elementref

Hi i am trying to make dynamic filter option that renders the property with their values on the basis of data entered by backend. On selecting value i want to fetch the checked values and pass it to backend for filtering. I am able to display the Filter option but when we select the checkbox unable to get the checked values.

I am using element ref and view Child to do so.

HTML Page :

```
<div #propertyFilterDiv id="{{propertyFilterData?.name}}" *ngFor="let propertyFilterData of propertyFiltersData" class="collection-filter-block">
    <div class="collection-mobile-back" (click)="toggleMobileSidebar()">
        <span class="filter-back">
            <i class="fa fa-angle-left" aria-hidden="true"></i> back
        </span>
    </div>

    <div   class="collection-collapse-block border-0 open">
        <h3   class="collapse-block-title">{{propertyFilterData?.name}}</h3>
        <div   class="collection-collapse-block-content">
            <div   class="collection-brand-filter">
                <ul   class="category-list">
                    <li *ngFor="let propertyvalue of propertyFilterData?.values ">
                        <div class="container-fluid">
                            <input value="{{propertyvalue?.value}}" class="property_{{propertyFilterData?.id}}"  (click)="filterData($event)" type="checkbox" />
                            <a > {{propertyvalue?.value}} </a>
                        </div>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

</div>
```

TS Code.

```
  filterData(e){
    this.propertyFilterDiv.forEach(propertyFilter =>{
      console.log(propertyFilter.nativeElement.id)
      console.log(propertyFilter.nativeElement.children)
    });
  }
```

Any help will be deeply appreciated. Need a guidance on same and best apporach to filter the data.

Answer (score 0):

On your click event you can pass the property id to your filterData method

```
(click)="filterData($event, propertyvalue)"
```

And use it for filtering

```
  filterData(e, propertyValue){ ... }
```

If you want to keep a track of the list of checked values, initiate it firt, for example :

```
listOfCheckedProperties = { propA: true, propB: false, propC: false };
```

And update it (check/uncheck) on your filterData function triggered by click.

You can also use ngModel to keep track automatically, look at angular forms : https://angular.io/guide/forms

Comment: Thanks for reply but I wanted to get all the selected values from checkbox collection and that collection will be collected in objects here and passed to server.

Comment: I guess am failing to explain you my case. I am having filters that comes from the database that i am rendering which may change in some other product category. When we check a element i am looking for all selected value using querySelector. Buy am getting just one element. Need your guidance on this.